# Building an S3 type of Storage Cloud

Tags: cloud, saas

Are there any  open source projects to build Storage as a Service type of Clouds like Amazon S3 ??

Comment: This is rather vague and hard to answer. Can you be more specific about the kind of project you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Eucalyptus has a storage interface called walrus. It is exactly similar and compatible with Amazon S3 and it is open source. You can try Eucalyptus.

Take a look at :

http://open.eucalyptus.com/downloads

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Openstack is another option for this type of build out.

Comment: Thanks :)  both Walrus and OpenStack seem to solve the problem.

But personally Walrus on Eucalyptus seems to be a better pick cause of the S3 integration.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out OpenStack Swift, the open source object storage solution. Its already in production at Rackspace, Hpcloud, Wikipedia, Internap, Korea Telecom.

You should check http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/ Apart from that you can also check associated projects http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/associated_projects.html

Hope it helps.